# Dynamic SUMIF with filter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have looked at different ways to do this by reading articles here and on Google, but I just can't get my `sumif` formula to be dynamic.  The formula below works, but when I filter, the answer stays the same. What I want is that when I change the filter, the sum will change as well. Currently, it is staying static and giving me the sum for the whole data.

```
SUMIF(_Option_AB,"A",'Results'!$DS$14:$DS$159)/SUMIF(_Option_AB,"A",'Results'!$DX$14:$DX$159)
```

The image I have is just an example as the real content is sensitive:

[image]

Comment: The comment by @underscore_d may well do the trick.  If not, have you considered using a pivot table?  It would be a lot easier

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for the late reply... The link that plato77 sent worked for me.. Thanks